# How to get SQL Server login mappings & role membership for a user

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I technically need this from a code in C#, but SQL would work as well. Say, I have a SQL Server 2008 or later login or a user account. Let's call it `c_user002`.

1. How do I get databases mapped to this user?
2. How do I get role membership (or permissions) for this user?

Both concepts can be best illustrated via a screenshot from the SQL Server Management Studio:

[image]

Comment: check this user default database setting

Comment: @Izikon: Sorry I'm not following you. Can you elaborate? (I need this in code.)

Comment: in the login properties screen (the screenshot you've uploaded ) , go to general and check the default database of the user

Answer (score 1):

Here's a partial answer. You can find out which users have which permissions on which objects using this query:

```
SELECT
         dp.name AS DBUser,
         dp.type_desc AS UserType,
         OBJECT_NAME(p.major_id) AS ObjectName,
         p.permission_name AS Permission,
         p.state_desc AS PermissionStatus,
         dp.is_fixed_role AS BuiltInRole
FROM
         sys.database_permissions AS p
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    sys.database_principals AS dp
    ON
    dp.principal_id = p.grantee_principal_id 
 WHERE (p.class = 1); -- Limit to Object or Column;
```

Note that this only applies to the current database. You can always loop through to get them all though.

Comment: Hey thank you. And it didn't take 4 years to get an answer :)

Comment: Does it usually take 4 years? :-)